# Suggestions with java largest and smallest input

Tags: java, for-loop, while-loop

I am writing a program where you will be putting in temperatures by using a Scanner. You can put in as many temperatures as you want and when you enter -100 the program will stop up and then give you the minimum, maximum, average and total registered temperatures. I have been successful with some but can not figure out how to get minimum, total numbers and average working. Been stuck here for some time now.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Tempratureprograme {
public static void main(String[] args) {

    temperatures();

}
public static void temperatures(){
    double temperature; 
    double biggest = 0;
    double smallest = 0;
    double totalNum = 0; 
    double counter = 1;
    int numberAmount = 0;
    double average = totalNum/numberAmount;

    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Please enter the temperature(s) - end the program with -100");
    System.out.print("-> ");


    do {
        temperature = input.nextDouble();
        numberAmount++;
        totalNum = totalNum + temperatur;
        System.out.print("-> ");

        if(temperature > max)
        {
            max=temperature;
            counter= 0;
        }

        if(temperature < min)
        {
            min = temperature;
        }

    }

    while (temperature != -100);
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println("Highest temperature: " + max);
    System.out.println("Lowest temperature: " + min);
    System.out.println("Average temprature: " + average); 
    System.out.println("Total registered tempratures: " + totalNum);



}
}
```

Comment: What's the problem? Why are you resetting the count if the temperature is higher? Also typo here: `totalNum = totalNum + temperatur;` (temperatur instead of temperature).

Comment: Are you sure you want to include `-100` into data? Because you are doing so right now.

Comment: Looks like you have not declared 'max' and 'min' variables. You'll have to declare those (or rename 'biggest'/'smallest' to max/min).

Comment: if you enter -3, -4,-10, -100 it'll tell you the highest number entered was 0.

Comment: If you init `max` with 0, it will not be updated when entering only negative numbers.

Comment: Guys I am totally new to this. If I am doing something wrong please help me. I dont know what the MIN and MAX will be because the user have to input that...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, You can not initialize min with 0, because whenever you try to match a positive temperature with it the if will always fail.
The following code should work

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {

    temperatures();

}
public static void temperatures(){
    int counter = 0;
    double temperature; 
    double totalNum = 0; 
    int numberAmount = 0;
    double max = - Double.MAX_VALUE;
    double min = Double.MAX_VALUE;
    double average = 0;

    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Please enter the temperature(s) - end the program with -100");
    System.out.print("-> ");


    while ((temperature = input.nextDouble()) != -100) {
      //  temperature = input.nextDouble();
        counter++;
        numberAmount++;
        totalNum = totalNum + temperature;
        System.out.print("-> ");

        if(temperature > max)
        {
            max=temperature;

        }

        if(temperature < min)
        {
            min = temperature;
        }

    }

    average = totalNum/numberAmount;
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println("Highest temperature: " + max);
    System.out.println("Lowest temperature: " + min);
    System.out.println("Average temprature: " + average); 
    System.out.println("Total registered tempratures: " + counter);



}
```

Comment: Hi!
Everything is working good except the Total registered tempratures:
I entered 4 tempratures but it was telling me i have entered 65??

Comment: It looks like the total tempratures is giving me a return after plussing all the tempratures. But I need the total of the doubles the user have input.

Comment: use a counter and increment it every time a user input takes place.

Comment: Hi still cannot get it working. Maybe I am editing it wrongly?

Comment: The code which you are trying - Please paste it on the question.I am able to run this code with the proper output.

Answer (score 0):

You should put this code after your `for` loop to compute the average and not before:

```
double average = totalNum/numberAmount;
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess that should do the trick

```
public static void temperatures() {
    double temperature;
    double biggest = 0;
    double smallest = 0;
    double totalNum = 0;
    double counter = 1;
    int numberAmount = 0;
    double average = totalNum / numberAmount;

    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Please enter the temperature(s) - end the program with -100");
    System.out.print("-> ");

    while ((temperature = input.nextDouble()) != -100) {
        numberAmount++;
        totalNum = totalNum + temperature;
        average=totalNum/numberAmount;

        if (temperature > biggest) {
            biggest = temperature;
        }
        if (temperature < smallest) {
            smallest = temperature;
        }
        System.out.print("-> ");
    }

    System.out.println();
    System.out.println("Highest temperature: " + biggest);
    System.out.println("Lowest temperature: " + smallest);
    System.out.println("Average temprature: " + average);
    System.out.println("Total registered tempratures: " + totalNum);

}
```

Comment: how come? What is wrong? Ofc you have to use `numberAmount` on the end insteed of `totalNum` but anything else? I didnt tested it, but it looks fine except that when we are dealing with floating point we should use straight comparision (`==` and `!=`) due to rounding and truncation errors, but thats preatty it I think.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution using Collections

```
 public static void temperatures(){
double temperature = 0; 
 double totalNum = 0; 
 double numberAmount = 0;
 List<Double> d= new ArrayList<Double>();
 Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

 System.out.println("Please enter the temperature(s) - end the program with -100");
 System.out.print("-> ");

  while (true){
   temperature = input.nextDouble();
     if (-100 == temperature) {
     break;
     }
     d.add(temperature);
     totalNum = totalNum+temperature;
     System.out.print("-> ");

 }
  numberAmount = d.size();

  System.out.println();
  System.out.println("Highest temperature: " + Collections.max(d));
  System.out.println("Lowest temperature: " +  Collections.min(d));
  System.out.println("Average temprature: " + totalNum/numberAmount); 
  System.out.println("Total registered tempratures: " + numberAmount);
  System.out.println("Sum of registered tempratures: " + totalNum);
}
```